# awscli iam update-role call incorrectly claiming required argument is missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

[This AWS page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/enable-federated-api-access-to-your-aws-resources-for-up-to-12-hours-using-iam-roles/) suggests the following invocation:

```
$ aws iam update-role -–role-name ADFS-Production -–max-session-duration 14400
```

When I run this (substituting the correct role name) I get

```
aws: error: the following arguments are required: --role-name
```

This is pretty confusing, because the argument is right there!

```
$ aws --version
```

on my machine gives

```
aws-cli/1.14.69 Python/3.6.4 Darwin/16.3.0 botocore/1.9.22
```

I tried stepping through the arg parsing with the debugger, and it looked like maybe the problem was that the list of option_string_actions isn't being populated right:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/argparse.py(2093)_parse_optional()
-> if arg_string in self._option_string_actions:
(Pdb) l
2088            # if it doesn't start with a prefix, it was meant to be positional
2089            if not arg_string[0] in self.prefix_chars:
2090                return None
2091    
2092            # if the option string is present in the parser, return the action
2093 ->         if arg_string in self._option_string_actions:
2094                action = self._option_string_actions[arg_string]
2095                return action, arg_string, None
2096    
2097            # if it's just a single character, it was meant to be positional
2098            if len(arg_string) == 1:
(Pdb) self._option_string_actions
{}
```

but it's pretty complicated, so it's hard to be sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you copy/paste this syntax from somewhere?  From what you are showing,  `-–role-name` has two different symbols in front of it, `-–` and they are visually dissimilar `-` (dash) and `–` (an n-dash, maybe?) instead of `--` as it should.  Type the command line by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran your command and something is not right with your `--`. Can you please try the following command (I changed nothing but your `--`:

```
aws iam update-role --role-name ADFS-Production --max-session-duration 14400
```

Comment: This is supposed to be a comment, not an answer, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks! I just copied it from that page assuming it was fine, but I guess something on their end replaced a dash with something fancy.

Comment: Seems different types of dashes are mishandled by the CLI interpreter;